# tkinter to display the images

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a newbie to python.I have a code where the image is not printed on the Tkinter.So please help me on how to display the image along with the Button and Textbox.

Code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
class myproject(Tkinter.Tk):
            def __init__(self,parent):
                Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
                self.button2()
                self.text()
                self.image()
            def button2(self):
                button2 = Tkinter.Button(self, text = "hello")
                button2.grid(column=5,row=7)
            def text(self):
                text = Tkinter.Text(self, height=3, width=31) # self.text
                text.grid(column=1,row=3)
                text.insert(END, "Wiilliam Skakespeare")

            def image(self):

                logo = PhotoImage(file="linux.gif")
                w1 = Tkinter.Label(self, image=logo).pack(side="right")


app = myproject(None)
app.mainloop()
```

Please help!Answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to save a reference to the photo image.**

See [this page for](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) more information, or [this one](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

There are numerous other problems with the code you posted, however; you need colons after function and class declarations, for example. When posting code, there's also no need for extraneous methods in the class, they only make it more difficult to understand

You also *cannot mix managers* or you're whole program might stall. This means you shouldn't be using *pack* and *grid* in the same program. Read through the effbot tutorial, it's really helpful!

```
class myproject(Tkinter.Tk):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)

            self.image()


        def image(self):

            logo = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file='linux.gif')
            self.logo = logo # You always need a reference to the image or it gets garbage collected
            w1 = Tkinter.Label(self, image=logo).grid()


app = myproject(None)
app.mainloop()
```