# Troubles uploading images in tkinter

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to use images writing a tkinter app with the following code:
[In a class's init function]

```
self.canvas = Canvas(self.root,
                     width = SCREEN_WIDTH,
                     height = SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                     bg = "light blue")

# The bird
bird = PhotoImage(file = 'angry_bird.png') # or gif
bird_height = self.bird_height()
self.bird = Label(self.canvas, image = bird)
self.bird.place(x = 25, y = bird_height)

# The target
target = PhotoImage(file = "pig.png") # or gif
target_coords = self.target_coordinates()
self.target = Label(self.canvas, image = target)
self.target.place(x = target_coords[0], y = target_coords[1])
```

When I run the code, the pictures ("pig.png", "angry_birds.png" - I tried the same and got the same result using gif files) appear as grey rectangles, not as pictures.

I also tried displaying the pictures that way - but here even the grey rectangles did not appear:

```
    # The bird
    bird = PhotoImage(file = 'angry_bird.png') # or gif
    bird_height = self.bird_height()
    self.bird = self.canvas.create_image(25, bird_height, image = bird)

    # The target
    target = PhotoImage(file = "pig.png") # or gif
    target_coords = self.target_coordinates()
    self.target = self.canvas.create_image(target_coords[0], target_coords[1], image = target)
```

Is there anything wrong?
Are there other ways?

Please don't offer not-built-in modules solutions

Thanks a lot
Dave

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25799374/7432

Comment: It does, thank you!!